# Running .jar File using JDK on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans

I install JDK on my Ubuntu 14.04 so I can use Netbeans and Android studio. I download a .jar file in the internet and I want to run it on my PC. My problem is, I cannot find java to run this file. I already allow executing file as a program. Do I need to install Java Run time? Cause, as far as it is said here, JDK already contains JRE. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1906455

Comment: You should be able to run Java jar files. What's the output of `java -version`?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to run Java jar files in terminal by running [java -jar path/to/jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html). Note that some jar files only print things out; they don't display a window.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you installed it.  If you're going for "My workspace is portable.  So I just extract zips/archives everywhere" then you need to check out update-alternatives:

```
schadenfreude@oubliette:~$ update-alternatives --display java
java - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```